# Top x% of a list SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, row-number

I have a query that orders a list depending on the amount of sales a client did:

```
Select
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Order By SUM(Price) desc) [Row_Number]
    ,Agent
    ,SUM(Price) as Total_Price
From
    foobar
Where
    Year_Number = 2015
Group By
    Agent
    ,p.National_Agent_Desc
```

This also gives each row a number 1 through how ever many agents there are. I need to get the bottom 25% of sales.

So I added the above query to a subquery, and calculated what # is the bottom 25% and then just filter on where Row_Number >= my calculation, below:

```
CAST(ROUND(CAST(CAST((MAX(ref.[Row_Number]) * 25) as decimal(12,2)) / 100 as decimal(12,2)),0) as int)
```

This gives me a number, but when I add it to the filter of the outer query, it doesn't bring back the bottom 25 rows (there are 100 records in this example).

Is there an easier way to filter this list by bottom 25% than to break out what ever number is the 25% and then create a 2nd query using that number?

Comment: Maybe look into NTILE

Comment: Why don't you use TOP 25 PERCENT? If you order by Total_Price ASC, this will give you the bottom 25% of sales

Comment: Interesting, Using Mihai's option, I get 24 rows returned, and using Panagiotis's option I get 25 rows returned. For reference there are 99 Agents in my list. So one rounds up, while the other rounds down.

Comment: Probably because you had to reverse the order with TOP 25 PERCENT.  Instead of getting the bottom 25 % you're getting the TOP in reverse order.   NTILE lets you truly get the bottom.